# How to use hook_entity_presave?

Tags: 7, commerce, entities, hooks

I have a product type called package. It is a package of another product type which is called applications; when a user wants to create or update a package , I want to calculate the price of the package by adding the price of all applications in that package . I want to use **[hook_entity_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7.x)**. but it doesn't work. I have put my function here.

My question: what should I check exactly against the `$entity->type`? My node type? Or my product type? It doesn't work either way.

```
function itunesdev_entity_presave(&$entity, $type) {
  if($entity->type == 'package') {
    $product_ids = array();   
    foreach($entity->field_products[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $key => $pid)
      $product_ids[] = $pid['target_id'];   
    $products = entity_load('commerce_product', $product_ids);   
    // reset default price
    $entity->commerce_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount'] = 0;
    foreach($products as $pid => $product) {
      $entity->commerce_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount'] += $product->commerce_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "doesn't work" a bit? Is the price of the package product being set to zero, or is not being altered at all? When you say you have a product of type "package", is that a `commerce_product`, or a product display node? If it's a commerce product you're checking the right var in the first `if`, but to make sure you're acting on the right entity type that should be `if ($type == 'commerce_product' && $entity->type == 'package') {`. That won't (or shouldn't) make a difference to your code working or not though

Comment: I have a product type which called **'package'** and a product display node which called **'package_display'**. the worst part is that no kind of die or var_dump helps me to get the result and find out what's wrong? should I test my code by adding a new 'package_display' node or new 'package' product?

Comment: @Aboodred1 I can't get any kind of result, even 'krumo' or die doesn't show up on save or update.

Comment: @weber85 you need to remove & from &$entity argument  then you'll be able test it using `krumo` or `print_r`

Comment: tanx a lot ... I can test it now...

Answer (score -3):

> Function hook_entity_presave acts on an entity before it is about to be created or updated

Code:

```
  function hook_entity_presave($entity, $type) {
    $entity->changed = REQUEST_TIME;
  }
```

source :  [Drupal API](https://goo.gl/nf0QZa)